# "UnCSS: Configuration missed" on Travis

Tags: travis-ci, brunch, uncss

I'm setting up [uncss-brunch](https://github.com/jakubburkiewicz/uncss-brunch) with Travis on a [test project](https://github.com/arturocastro/quacknote). `brunch build` works well locally, but when I push changes, the build on Travis fails. The error line reads:

```
18 Apr 22:38:59 - error: UnCSS: Configuration missed.
```

Any ideas on what may be wrong, or how may I debug this? I've found that the error message is from the [uncss-brunch](https://github.com/jakubburkiewicz/uncss-brunch/blob/08b12c7853e3156d01a0a31f21d97fcae5d2d907/index.js#L71) project itself.

Comment: Try it on a fresh clone. Check and adjust for version differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it was working locally is because optimizers normally aren't run in development mode. On Travis, however, you are running `npm run dist` with runs `brunch build -p` — a build in production env.

If you were to run `brunch build -p` locally, it would give the same result as on Travis.

Now, the actual reason for that happening seems to be that you are missing a configuration for UnCSS.

If you take a closer look at the file you've linked, you'll see that the error is printed because `this.options` is `null`. And `this.options` is set from `config.plugins.uncss` — which is seemingly missing from your `brunch-config` — https://github.com/arturocastro/quacknote/blob/master/brunch-config.js

Check out UnCSS's [readme](https://github.com/jakubburkiewicz/uncss-brunch#config) on how to configure it.

Comment: Thanks, I've also read [this issue](https://github.com/jakubburkiewicz/uncss-brunch/issues/) as additional help.